# visualizing Start and stop date on google chart

Tags: javascript, date, gantt-chart

it's a few weeks that I'm using the gantt charts from google, I have several problem:
Check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/b906dhwr/):

- I want to be able to see the date of when a certain activity starts, if you check my example, I can only see the start and stop hour, as you can see the chart starts in a day and finish in an other, but right now I can't see the start and stop date.
  So basically I want to see that an order start the 22/09/2018 at 08:05, or if that is not possible, instead of 12 AM or PM I want to see the date of that day, like 22/09/2018

If you check my example, I've insert the right start and stop date `[ 'M01 Guarnizione', 'M01 Guarnizione', 'Guarnizione', new Date(2018,09,22,08,05), new Date(2018,09,22,11,57), null, 0, null],`

Comment: `new Date(2018,09,22,08,05)` creates a Date for 22 October, not September.

Comment: yeah, I know, because the months are counted from 0 to 11, but except that do you know how to show the date?